# How to scale img without pushing it to another line

Tags: html, css, image

i have 3 images in div and when i resize my browser, the images doesn't scale, they just move to another line under each other. I want them to scale first and then they can move down but i don't know how to achieve that please help.

```
<div class="jak-d">
<img class="jak-op" style="margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;" alt="" src="/library/images/im1.png" />
<img class="jak-op" style="margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;" alt="" src="/library/images/im2.png" />
<img class="jak-op" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;" alt="" src="/library/images/im3.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.jak-d{
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  margin-top:70px;
  margin-bottom:100px;
}
.jak-op{
  opacity:0.5;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap responsive images. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

```
 <img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

Just include the plugin and add the class `img-responsive` to your `image tag` and voila.

**OR** simply use its `class` only -

```
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

**In your case**

```
.jak-op{
  opacity:0.5;
  max-width:100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your images width to 100% too, not just the max-width.

```
.jak-d{
 height:auto;
 max-width:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin-top:70px;
 margin-bottom:100px;
}
.jak-op{
 opacity:0.5;
 max-width:100%;
 width:100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks, will it work if i switch width for height? so they all have same height when i change the size of a browser but width is different in each image?

Comment: Same concept so yes.  If you define heght by pixel, all heights will have the same pixels, no matter how you resize the window. If you define it by percentil "%", then they will always all have the same percentage towards the page size.  So yeah, it will work :)

Comment: well it doesn't :D it works fine with width but with height it scales a bit down when i set it to 25% but it doesn't change when browser change

Comment: it seems that the ratio is weird because it's not 25% of the height for sure